# How do I 'append' a dictionary into an existing JSON dictionary using python?

Tags: python, json, database, dictionary, append

## Take a look at this example dictionary:

This is in a JSON file:

```
{
   "fridge": {
       "vegetables": {
            "Cucumber": 0,
            "Carrot": 2,
            "Lettuce": 5
       },
       "drinks": {
            "Water": 12,
            "Juice": 4,
            "Soda": 2 
       }
    }
}
```

So in this example, we are showing the contents of my fridge, except we show the AMOUNT (2) of every ITEM (soda) in every CATEGORY (drinks). The way we did this, we firstly created a dictionary for the fridge and for every category we have another dictionary where inside it we have the item-type and amount of it.

Now let's say we went shopping... We bought some FRUITS at the supermarket and we got:

```
"fruits": {
   "Apple": 3,
   "Banana": 2,
   "Melon": 1
}
```

We want to put this data (or fruits) into my fridge, except we don't have a CATEGORY for "fruits"!! So not only do we have to add a new dictionary into my fridge, but we also have data that we want to already add too!

Now this fridge thing was an example to help you understand what I want. So how do you insert a new dictionary into an already existing one with key-value pairs in it? In other words, I want my fridge to look like this:

```
{
   "fridge": {
       "vegetables": {
          "Cucumber": 0,
          "Carrot": 2,
          "Lettuce": 5
       },
       "drinks": {
          "Water": 12,
          "Juice": 4,
          "Soda": 2 
      },
      "fruits": {
          "Apple": 3,
          "Banana": 2,
          "Melon": 1
      }
   }
}
```

I tried APPEND but as expected, it does not work for dictionaries (it is for lists only) and so I do not know what to do... keep in mind that I do not want to re-define my data, I want to ADD data to existing data so that I can edit it later. Would appreciate some help, Thanks!

Comment: Here, I started the discussion, comment some ideas, thanks

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets_add.asp

Comment: Your file is not valid JSON to start with... Should be `{"fridge": {"vegetables": {"Cucumber": 0, "Carrot": 2, "Lettuce": 5}, "drinks": {"Water": 12, "Juice": 4, "Soda": 2}}}`

Comment: @macroland sorry, but that is SETS, which is different to dicts. Dicts store in key-value pairs while sets are almost like a normal list

Comment: @dawg fixed, yes sorry, I made a mistake copying

Comment: Dicts have a method "update" which should work here.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this string in proper json format:

```
j_str1='''\
{"fridge": {
    "vegetables": {
        "Cucumber": 0,
        "Carrot": 2,
        "Lettuce": 5
    },
    "drinks": {
        "Water": 12,
        "Juice": 4,
        "Soda": 2 
    }
}}'''
```

And:

```
j_str2='''\
{"fruits": {
    "Apple": 3,
    "Banana": 2,
    "Melon": 1
}}
'''
```

First convert to a Python dict:

```
import json

j=json.loads(j_str1)
>>> j
{'fridge': {'vegetables': {'Cucumber': 0, 'Carrot': 2, 'Lettuce': 5}, 'drinks': {'Water': 12, 'Juice': 4, 'Soda': 2}}}
```

Then update:

```
j["fridge"].update(json.loads(j_str2))

>>> j
{'fridge': {'vegetables': {'Cucumber': 0, 'Carrot': 2, 'Lettuce': 5}, 'drinks': {'Water': 12, 'Juice': 4, 'Soda': 2}, 'fruits': {'Apple': 3, 'Banana': 2, 'Melon': 1}}}
```

Then convert back into json:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(j,indent=3))
{
   "fridge": {
      "vegetables": {
         "Cucumber": 0,
         "Carrot": 2,
         "Lettuce": 5
      },
      "drinks": {
         "Water": 12,
         "Juice": 4,
         "Soda": 2
      },
      "fruits": {
         "Apple": 3,
         "Banana": 2,
         "Melon": 1
      }
   }
}
```